# asp.net core delete everything with certain number

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

I want to delete all vragen(questions in english) with the classID for example number 5. It is possible to give a vraagID and a classID and the server deletes the question if it matches. But I want to delete all matching questions with only one request. Is this possible?

```
    namespace AspIdentityServer.data
    {
        public class Vraag :Conversatie
        {
            public int VraagID { get; set; }
            public int classID { get; set; }
            public string Titel { get; set; }

            public ICollection<Antwoord> Antwoord { get; set; }
            public Vak Vak { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

**--**

```
      // DELETE: api/Vraags/1/alles/5
                [AllowAnonymous]
                [HttpDelete("{id}/alles/{vakID}")]
                public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteAlleVragen([FromRoute] int id, int vakID) {
                    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        return BadRequest(ModelState);
                    }
                    var vraag = await _context.Vraag.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.VraagID == id);

                    if (vraag.classID == vakID)
                    {
                        _context.Vraag.Remove(vraag);
                        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    }
                    return Ok(vraag);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the `ExecuteSqlCommandAsync` to execute your custom SQL queries. So write a single delete statements with appropriate where clause which will handle many rows as needed.

Here is a quick example

```
object[] paramsArray =
{
    new SqlParameter
    {
        ParameterName = "@vraagId",
        SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
        Value = id
    },
    new SqlParameter
    {
        ParameterName = "@classId",
        SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
        Value = vakID
    }
};
const string q = "DELETE FROM VraagWHERE VraagID=@vraagId and ClassId=@classId";
await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(q, paramsArray);
```

Update the SQL statemenets and parameters as needed.